# Change Visual Studio 2017 from Mobile Development back to Web Development

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, xamarin-studio

I have a copy of VS 2017 and a few months ago I configured my copy to enable mobile development with Xamarin. Now I need to develop a new web project and as a result of what I did I need to revert it back as none of my previous projects will work and creating a new project only offers mobile development which suited me fine before but not now, I need my VS 2017 to be for web development again but don't know how to change it back.

Whenever I use Google for some tips I just get information on development for mobiles. I'm sure someone has done this so if they can tell me how to revert my VS back I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You should just need to run the installer, and select the applicable workload.  It sounds like you removed the web development workload when you installed the mobile workload.

Comment: I believe this can also be configured in Add/Remove programs, it offers you an option to repair the installation then you can reset your configuration.

Comment: Thank you Brendan, that worked perfectly and I kept my Mobile setup so I now have both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just need to run the installer, select modify and select the applicable workload. It sounds like you removed the web development workload when you installed the mobile workload as you can have any combination (Brendan Green)